# Loading bitmap manually

Tags: c#, bitmap, bmp

I'm trying to write some C# code, which will take an name to a .bmp located on the disk. 
To that I have been following the wikipedia page : [BMP File Format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format)

So i have created 2 classes to contain the headers.
Firstly the file header :

```
    class BMPFileHeader
    {
        public BMPFileHeader(Byte[] headerBytes)
        {
            // Position
            int offset = 0;

            // Read 2 byes
            bfType = ((char)headerBytes[0]).ToString();
            bfType += ((char)headerBytes[1]).ToString();
            offset = offset + 2;
            // Read 4 bytes to uint32
            bfSize = BitConverter.ToUInt32(headerBytes, offset);
            offset = offset + sizeof(UInt32);

            // Read 2 bytes to uint16
            bfReserved1 = BitConverter.ToUInt16(headerBytes, offset);
            offset = offset + sizeof(UInt16);

            // Read 2 bytes to uint16
            bfReserved2 = BitConverter.ToUInt16(headerBytes, offset);
            offset = offset + sizeof(UInt16);

            // Read 4 bytes to uint32
            bfOffBits = BitConverter.ToUInt32(headerBytes, offset);
            offset = offset + sizeof(UInt32);
        }

        public string bfType;                      // Ascii characters "BM"
        public UInt32 bfSize;                      // The size of file in bytes
        public UInt16 bfReserved1;                 // Unused, must be zero
        public UInt16 bfReserved2;                 // Same ^^
        public UInt32 bfOffBits;                   // Pixel offset [ where pixel array starts ]
    }
```

Which seems to work just fine. So moving on to the next header, the image Header. :

```
    class BMPImageHeader
    {
        public BMPImageHeader(Byte[] headerBytes)
        {
            // Position
            int offset = 0;

            biSize = BitConverter.ToUInt32(headerBytes, offset);
            offset = offset + sizeof(UInt32);

            biWidth = BitConverter.ToUInt32(headerBytes, offset);
            offset = offset + sizeof(UInt32);

            biHeight = BitConverter.ToUInt32(headerBytes, offset);
            offset = offset + sizeof(UInt32);

            biPlanes = BitConverter.ToUInt16(headerBytes, offset);
            offset = offset + sizeof(UInt16);

            biBitCount = BitConverter.ToUInt16(headerBytes, offset);
            offset = offset + sizeof(UInt16);

            biCompression = BitConverter.ToUInt32(headerBytes, offset);
            offset = offset + sizeof(UInt32);

            biSizeImage = BitConverter.ToUInt32(headerBytes, offset);
            offset = offset + sizeof(UInt32);

            XPelsPerMeter = BitConverter.ToUInt32(headerBytes, offset);
            offset = offset + sizeof(UInt32);

            YPelsPerMeter = BitConverter.ToUInt32(headerBytes, offset);
            offset = offset + sizeof(UInt32);

            biClrUsed = BitConverter.ToUInt32(headerBytes, offset);
            offset = offset + sizeof(UInt32);

            biClrImportant = BitConverter.ToUInt32(headerBytes, offset);
            offset = offset + sizeof(UInt32);
        }

        public UInt32 biSize;          // Size of header, must be least 40
        public UInt32 biWidth;         // Image width in pixels
        public UInt32 biHeight;        // Image height in pixels
        public UInt16 biPlanes;        // Must be 1
        public UInt16 biBitCount;      // Bits per pixels.. 1..4..8..16..32    
        public UInt32 biCompression;   // 0 No compression
        public UInt32 biSizeImage;     // Image size, may be zer for   uncompressed
        public UInt32 XPelsPerMeter;   // Preferred resolution in pixels per meter
        public UInt32 YPelsPerMeter;   // Same ^^
        public UInt32 biClrUsed;       // Number color map entries
        public UInt32 biClrImportant;  // Number of significant colors


    }
```

Which also seems to work.. So now i have some important information for disp
laying that picture.

```
biBitCount = bits per pixel
biHeight = height in pixel
biWidth  = width in pixel
bfOffBit = Pixel array offset
```

So as the clever man I thought i were.
I would start copy them to a struct 2D array I've created containing 3 bytes. RED,GREEN and BLUE. 
So read all rest of file to a buffer. And run through that buffer 3 bytes at time, and add a pixel made of theese 3 bytes.

```
    public ImageManipulation(string _name, string _imageLocation)
    {
        // Set name
        Name = _name;

        // Initialize classes
        //fHeader = new BMPFileHeader();
        //iHeader = new BMPImageHeader();

        if (File.Exists(_imageLocation))
        {
            int offset = 0;
            Byte[] fsBuffer;
            FileStream fs = File.Open(_imageLocation, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);

            // Start by reading file header..
            fsBuffer = new Byte[14]; // size 40 bytes
            fs.Read(fsBuffer, 0, 14);
            fHeader = new BMPFileHeader(fsBuffer);

            // Then image header, 40 bytes
            fsBuffer = new Byte[40];
            fs.Read(fsBuffer, 0, 40);
            iHeader = new BMPImageHeader(fsBuffer);

            // Apply pixels
            Pixels = new RGBPixel[iHeader.biHeight, iHeader.biWidth];

            // How many bytes per pixel
            int bpi = iHeader.biBitCount/8;

            // Read pixel array
            long totalBytes = iHeader.biWidth*iHeader.biHeight*bpi;

            if (totalBytes == iHeader.biSizeImage) ;
            if (iHeader.biSizeImage == ( fHeader.bfSize - (iHeader.biSize + 14))) ;

            // Create butter, read data
            fsBuffer = new Byte[iHeader.biWidth*iHeader.biHeight*bpi];
            fs.Read(fsBuffer, 0, (int)fHeader.bfOffBits);

            int RowSize = ((iHeader.biBitCount *(int) iHeader.biWidth + 31) / 32) * 4;


            int x, y;
            x = y = 0;

            long i;
            int lcounter = 0;

            // This reads 3 bytes a time 
            for (i = 0; i < totalBytes; i = i + 3)
            {
                    // Read 3 bytes
                    Pixels[ (iHeader.biHeight-1) - y, x].RED = fsBuffer[i];
                    Pixels[ (iHeader.biHeight-1) - y, x].GREEN = fsBuffer[i + 1];
                    Pixels[ (iHeader.biHeight-1) - y, x].BLUE = fsBuffer[i + 2];

                    // Update position in array
                    x++;
                    if (x == iHeader.biWidth)
                    {
                        y++;
                        x = 0;
                    }
            }
        }
    }
```

I don't get any errors running and compiling this code, but the Image i create afterwards with Bitmap.setPixel() is almost just black.  So i read the pixels somehow wrong, but i cannot determine why??

The image i use to test this is [image: Experiment image]

And what i get is this : [image: My image]

Thanks
Any helps is appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not clear why you are under the impression that pixels in a bitmap are stored in the way you describe. Two bytes of padding between every six bytes of pixel data?

There is no padding at all between pixels *within a scan line*. If you have a 24bpp image, then the pixels are stored three bytes at a time, in a single contiguous array of three-byte pixels.

Perhaps you are confusing the *per-row* padding? A whole scan line is padding out *only at the very end* to a multiple of 4 bytes (32 bits). Typically, the way one would handle this is to compute the "stride" of the bitmap, which is just another word for the length in bytes of a single scan line. Then you would loop on the `x` and `y` coordinates within the bitmap, computing the byte offset for each new row anew based on the `y` value and the stride.

In the Wikipedia article you referenced, this is addressed under the heading of ["Pixel Storage"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format#Pixel_storage).

Having computed the stride, the actual code usually looks something like this (for 24bpp):

```
byte[] buffer = ...;

for (int y = 0, ibRow = 0; y < height; y++, ibRow += stride)
{
    for (int x = 0, ibPixel = ibRow; x < width; x++, ibPixel += 3)
    {
        byte red = buffer[ibPixel],
             green = buffer[ibPixel + 1],
             blue = buffer[ibPixel + 2];

        // do something with pixel data
    }
}
```

Naturally, you have to look at the bitmap header information to correctly determine things like the actual bits-per-pixel (3 bytes per pixel in this case, hence the `ibPixel += 3`), and the component order (the pixel bytes are not always red-green-blue...another common order is blue-green-red).

All that said, there is also the question of why you are trying to implement this at all. .NET already has various classes that allow you to load a bitmap image from a file, and even to gain access to the raw pixel data if needed. Why reinvent the wheel?

If simply as an academic exercise, that's fine, but if this is for real-world code I'd strongly suggest starting with one of the existing bitmap support classes in .NET. If you need direct access to the pixel data, you'll still need to concern yourself with things like the actual pixel format, stride, etc. but the bitmap support classes provide more convenient access to this than trying to interpret the file data itself directly, and in any case provide you with a fully usable *image* object as well.

Comment: Hi @Peter .
I work on this because of academic, I'm still not sure about this padding.
As far as i know the 00 padding will be counted with in the total file size right?

But when i do : totalBytes = Height x Width x BytesPerPixel 

it is equal to : bfSize - ( (40) iHeader size + (14) fHeader size)

Comment: @MrSykkox: What is the width? If e.g for a 24bpp image, the `width * 3` is already a multiple of 4 (i.e. `width` itself is a multiple of 4), no padding at all is needed.

Comment: Right now i try with a picture of 60x60

Comment: @MrSykkox: 60 / 4 = 15, exactly. There you go. No padding would be present in that file, because 60 is a multiple of 4.

Comment: So i edited my code, to not skip bytes for padding, 2 sec i will change in question.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Peter_Duniho who pointed me in correct way,i was confused over the padding which he cleared up for me.

My mistake was very simple error, in fs.Read() where instead of telling it to read the size of image, i asked it to read the offset.