# Loading a subrectangle of a bitmap using streams in C#

Tags: c#, io, bitmap, filestream

I have bitmap as bmp file (no compressions just a simple bitmap). I want to create memory stream from subsection (a rectangle) of the file without loading the whole file to memory.

Currently, I read the whole bitmap just to be cropped later using a rectangle that represents the points relative to the size of the image.

```
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(ImagePath, FileMode.Open)) 
{
                        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
                        fs.CopyTo(ms);
                        Image temp = Image.FromStream(ms, false, false);
}
```

Since bitmap is just a big matrix with color vectors as values can't I create a custom stream to read, only between relevant rows and columns to improve running time and memory usage? The manipulated image never leaves the memory or saved anywhere.

EDIT: Also is there a way to load the file straight to memory stream without using file stream at all?

Comment: Did you try loading the Image directly from the FileStream? The last question doesn't make too much sense for me. You want to read a file, so FileStream is the way to go. If implemented well, it will only read the necessary parts. What are your considerations in terms of performance? What is this code used for?

Comment: _just a simple bitmap_ Actually there are quite a number of subformats..

Comment: @Taw according to Wikipedia all bitmap bmp files store their image data in a pixel array, the only things change is pixel formats and I don't care for these all I care is accessing the relevant parts of the array and ignoring the parts I don't need.

Comment: @blackforest-tom I did. If I completely ignore MemoryStream and do Image.FromStream(fs) strait away in my case it would increase the running time two-fold. Apparently memory stream is more effective for objects in memory and this trick with CopyTo(ms) allows us to improve running time for objects that stay in memory.

Comment: I know that article and so I know that the pixel array may or may not be compressed and may or may not be upside down. Or may or may not be prefixed by various other elements including a color table. Of course you may (or may not) know best about the variations in your bitmaps but unless the normal way of reading images as images it really too slow, I wouldn't go into optimizing..

Comment: The short answer is yes, of course there is, but it's not trivial.  It's not super terribly difficult if there is an actual need for it, but expect a couple days to get it working.  All the information you need is here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format#:~:targetText=The%20BMP%20file%20format%2C%20also,and%20OS%2F2%20operating%20systems.

Comment: @TaW it's not that critical and I was mostly curious how to do it. runtime gains would also be nice since this reading operation is repeated 40 times.(I have total control over bmp creation)

Comment: @RobertMcKee Thanks that article is the one I'm currently using to try and do it myself, just hopped someone already did it before me :)

Comment: _I have total control over bmp creation_ Well two operations tend to be slower than others: reading/writing to/from disk and to the screen. The former will be faster with smaller file sizes, esp. with larger images, so stroing as png may well speed things up, as cpu is fast but disk is slow and compression may well pay off..

Comment: If you want to implement this, I would suggest creating a custom FileSteam object that takes the crop dimensions as part of it's constructor.  Not a great design, but you can then have the constructor read the header (first 4k), grab the offset of the array at offset 0xa, and the dimensions at 0x12 and 0x16.  Verify the compression at 0x1e is 0, and the header field at 0x00 is 0x42 0x4d, and header size at 0x0e is what you expect.  Then calculate the row size in bytes, jump to offset of the first row, and start processing.

Comment: Assuming your clip is defined as x,y,w,h.. then write out a simple header to a memory stream and start copying the image data to it.  Move the read pointer to `y*rowsize+x*bytesperpixel`.  Copy `w*bytesperpixel` to the memory stream.  skip `rowsize-w*bytesperpixel` bytes.  Repeat copy and skip h times.  Then hand back the memory stream.

Comment: @RobertMcKee thanks your comment and [answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28648974/loading-bitmap-manually) contains all the information I needed, all I left to do is just limit the for loops to relevant rows and columns.

Comment: Depending in your I/O subsystem, the size of the image and the crop area, this may actually not be faster than reading the entire image.  Disks are pretty good at streaming large amounts of data quickly.  Trying to skip portions of it is only beneficial in large predictable chunks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you want to create a custom FileStream that essentially ignores pixel data (by just returning zeros I suppose?) for any region outside of your subrectangle, and thus reduces the total amount of I/O. Yes, it's possible, but it's about as tricky as just writing your own image loader. Your stream would need to understand all the relevant bitmap header information (compression when applicable, bit depth, row order, padding) in order to determine the correct memory offsets for your subrectangle.

I'm not convinced that it will save you much I/O unless the subrectangle is *very* small compared to the original image. Hard drives will probably going to read data in chunks of about 4k bytes even when you request fewer, so for screen-sized images the biggest performance impact is going to be the total number of rows.

If I were going to go this route (loading only a subrectangle, that is) I would not do it with a custom stream. Instead, I would load the relevant metadata from the bitmap file headers and then create a GDI+ Bitmap object with the correct size and pixel format for the subrectangle. Then you can lock the bitmap and read the pixel data directly into the Bitmap object's memory.

It's not trivial, so don't do it unless you really need to.

Comment: are there any libraries that can already do this?